# How to solve syntax error with `ALTER TABLE` query?

Tags: sql

I’m having issues with syntax error in my queries, I’m trying to alter my table.

```
alter table people = person
```

Comment: Are you trying to rename the column or table named `person` to `people`? Renaming is not a standard SQL operation, so you'll have to tag your question with the RDBMS you're using (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etcetera), since they all have different approaches. Alternatively, you could be trying to `UPDATE`, or add a computed column, it's not possible to tell from your syntax. What does your table look like now and what do you expect it to look afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your question I dind't know what you were trying to rename if it was your table name or the column name.

For SQL Server to rename your column you can do this:

```
sp_rename 'table_name.old_column_name', 'new_column_name', 'COLUMN';
```

With your code should look like this:

```
sp_rename 'table_name.people', 'person', 'COLUMN';
```

Otherwise if you're trying to rename your table it will be like this:

```
sp_rename 'old_table_name', 'new_table_name';
```

With your code should look like this:

```
sp_rename 'people', 'person'
```

If you're trying to alter something else please check this document[1].

For MySQL or Oracle you can try the next document[2].

[1] https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp

[2]https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-alter-rename/